# App cache and GET method

Tags: django, html, caching, get

I am woriking on the simple webpage that can work offline in django.
In this project I am using app cache to store static files and local storage to keep dictionary. But I have encountered on the problem. Namely, I use GET method and my url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8000/search/?key=aaaa
```

But app cache keeps only "string" url, so every new query need connection with server.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, HTML5 Application Cache can only pre-download files in the manifest, so it cannot be used for stuff like caching search results.

I would suggest to store search results to the local storage (I'm assuming you are already using AJAX requests for the search):

- When user uses the search, look in the local storage whether you already have stored result for the current search, if so display it, if not:

  - if you are offline display some message like "You cannot use search while offline."
  - if you are online fetch the search result from the server, store it to the local storage and display it.